# Create Program reads Float Big Endian from game (Cemu) to get position of player

Tags: c#, endianness, converters

I learned a bit of the basics of C# language a couple years ago and now I'm slowly trying to increase knowledge of it through the creation of a trainer for a CEMU game i really enjoyed (hope i dont get criticized for my honesty).
Since i'm a noob at this i learned much from looking at another trainer that a programer released on gitHub, mostly copying classes and then trying to understand the how and why of things... Surely not the best way to learn but one has to start somewhre. But now i'm way out of my league.
I've managed to get offsets (2byte Big Endian) of many things (HP,Stamina,Speed, Stamina) and am able to chage values. Now i wanted to get player position and though i have right offsets i have no idea how work with Float Big Endian.
My repositary (not all files yet) is here:
https://github.com/Snowfall007/ZELDA-BOTW-Trainer
The class - ProcessWrapper is probably the key, but dont know how to work it.
Any good samaritan with patience and skill to help this kid at heart?

```
internal class ProcessWrapper
    {
        private readonly string _processName;
        private string _processLocation;
        private Kernel32.SafeHPROCESS _process;
        private long _baseAddress = 0x0;

        public ProcessWrapper(string processName)
        {
            _processName = processName;
        }

        public bool OpenProcess()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(_processName);

            if (processes.Length != 1)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Required rights : 0x0010 | 0x0400 | 0x0020 | 0x0008
            _process = Kernel32.OpenProcess(ACCESS_MASK.GENERIC_ALL, true, (uint)processes[0].Id);

            if (processes[0].MainModule == null) throw new Exception("Process main module is null.");

            _processLocation = processes[0].MainModule.FileName;

            return true;
        }

        public void SetBaseAddress(long baseAddress)
        {
            _baseAddress = baseAddress;
        }

        public bool OverwriteMemoryProtection(long address, int size)
        {
            return Kernel32.VirtualProtectEx(_process, (IntPtr)(_baseAddress + address), size, Kernel32.MEM_PROTECTION.PAGE_READWRITE, out Kernel32.MEM_PROTECTION oldProtection);
        }

        public byte[] ReadMemory(long address, int size, MemoryType memoryType)
        {
            IntPtr memoryReadPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

            Kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(_process, (IntPtr)(_baseAddress + address), memoryReadPtr, size, out SizeT readSize);

            byte[] memoryBuffer = new byte[readSize];
            Marshal.Copy(memoryReadPtr, memoryBuffer, 0, readSize);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memoryReadPtr);

            return ProcessMemoryType(memoryBuffer, memoryType);
        }

        public byte[] ReadMemory(Offset offset)
        {
            return ReadMemory(offset.Address, offset.Size, offset.MemoryType);
        }

        public bool WriteMemory(long address, byte[] data, MemoryType memoryType)
        {
            data = ProcessMemoryType(data, memoryType);

            IntPtr dataPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);

            Marshal.Copy(data, 0, dataPtr, data.Length);

            bool writeResult = Kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(_process, (IntPtr)(_baseAddress + address), dataPtr, data.Length, out SizeT wroteCount);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(dataPtr);

            return writeResult;
        }

        public bool WriteMemory(Offset offset, byte[] data)
        {
            return WriteMemory(offset.Address, data, offset.MemoryType);
        }

        public string GetProcessLocation()
        {
            return _processLocation;
        }

        private static byte[] ProcessMemoryType(byte[] data, MemoryType memoryType)
        {
            if (memoryType == MemoryType.BigEndian && data.Length > 1)
            {
                data = data.Reverse().ToArray();               
            }
            return data;
        }
    }


//In Form1 class i've have also these instructions:


//Coordinates
        //Position
        public int GetXPosition()
        {
            return ReadOffset(GameOffsets.Xposition);
        }
        public bool UpdateXPosition(int value)
        {
            return WriteOffset(GameOffsets.Xposition, value);
        }
        public int GetYPosition()
        {
            return ReadOffset(GameOffsets.Yposition);
        }
        public bool UpdateYPosition(int value)
        {
            return WriteOffset(GameOffsets.Yposition, value);
        }
        public int GetZPosition()
        {
            return ReadOffset(GameOffsets.Zposition);
        }
        public bool UpdateZPosition(int value)
        {
            return WriteOffset(GameOffsets.Zposition, value);
        }

//AND ALSO THIS:


private int ReadOffset(Offset offset)
        {
            byte[] data = _processWrapper.ReadMemory(offset);

            if (data.Length != offset.Size) return -1;
            else if (data.Length == 1) return data[0];
            else if (data.Length == 2) return BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0);

            throw new Exception("32 Bits and 64 Bits types are currently not handled");
        }
```

How can i make changes to work specifically with Float Big Endian?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-htonf

Comment: BinaryPrimitives.ReadSingleBigEndian

Comment: htonf seems to be only for c++ :(

Comment: Anyone else that give a more specific help?

Comment: How can i change this to accept/get Float Big Endian? private int ReadOffset(Offset offset)
        {
            byte[] data = _processWrapper.ReadMemory(offset);

            if (data.Length != offset.Size) return -1;
            else if (data.Length == 1) return data[0];
            else if (data.Length == 2) return BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 0);

            throw new Exception("32 Bits and 64 Bits types are currently not handled");
        }

Comment: Anybody there? ...